# How to transform data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python and I have a data frame like below:

```
In [5]: df.head()

         date       open     high      low    close  volume                                                        
2017-02-22 15:00  1.05131  1.05137  1.05074  1.05075     543
2017-02-22 15:30  1.05074  1.05165  1.05072  1.05139     506
2017-02-22 16:00  1.05137  1.05193  1.05121  1.05141     488
2017-02-22 16:30  1.05144  1.05205  1.05056  1.05065     747
2017-02-22 17:00  1.05061  1.05167  1.04988  1.04997     753
```

I need to transform the data frame into this format to input it to a LSTM model .

```
                    open     high      low    close  volume
date                                                        
2017-02-22 15:00  1.05131  1.05137  1.05074  1.05075     543
2017-02-22 15:30  1.05074  1.05165  1.05072  1.05139     506
2017-02-22 16:00  1.05137  1.05193  1.05121  1.05141     488
2017-02-22 16:30  1.05144  1.05205  1.05056  1.05065     747
2017-02-22 17:00  1.05061  1.05167  1.04988  1.04997     753
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```py
df = df.set_index('date')
df
                       open     high      low    close  volume
            date
2017-02-22 15:00    1.05131     1.05137     1.05074     1.05075     543
2017-02-22 15:30    1.05074     1.05165     1.05072     1.05139     506
2017-02-22 16:00    1.05137     1.05193     1.05121     1.05141     488
2017-02-22 16:30    1.05144     1.05205     1.05056     1.05065     747
2017-02-22 17:00    1.05061     1.05167     1.04988     1.04997     753
```

Comment: df.set_index('date', inplace=True) if you want to make it permanent